# c how to recognize UDT enum in .cpp from inside class class .h file?

Tags: c++, class

The compiler is giving me an error when I try to invoke the enum UDT Month in my .h file from my .cpp file. Can I use my enum UDT in another file? If so how?

my date.h

```
class Date 
{

public:

    enum Month
        {
        jan = 1, 
        feb, 
        mar, 
        apr, 
        may, 
        jun, 
        jul, 
        aug, 
        sep, 
        oct, 
        nov, 
        dec
        };

    Month int_to_month(int x);

    Date(int y, Month m, int d);

    Month month () const;

...other code


};
```

The compiler highlights errors for the following references to Month and the function names  in date.cpp file

```
#include "lib.h"
#include "date.h"

Month Date::month () const  
    {
    return m;
    }

Month Date::int_to_month(int x)
    {
    return m;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify where Month is coming from, like this:

```
Date::Month Date::month () const { /* ... */ }
Date::Month Date::int_to_month(int x) { /* ... */ }
```

Otherwise the compiler has no idea what Month is, and it's looking for something in the global scope with that name.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `Month` should be `Date::Month`, because the `enum` is a member of the class. If you want it to be straight `Month`, declare it at file scope.